# 1D Finite Difference Wave Equation Cuda

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, numerical-methods, finite-difference

I am new to Cuda. I am trying to solve the wave equation with the initial condition in the form of the Ricky momentum. The performance of the code is 12 GFlops, although my GPU performance is 3900. Why is the code so ineffective for me and how can I fix it?

main.cu

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "step.cu"
#include <cuda.h>
#include "err.cu"
#include "err.h"
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
        if (argc <= 3)
        {
                perror("Error in argc: argc<=3 (wait h, tau, C) \n");
                exit(1);
        }

  char *eptr;
  errno = 0;

  long long int size,tmax;
  double tau,cour,h,C, cour2;

  h = std::strtod(argv[1], &eptr);
  tau = std::strtod(argv[2], &eptr);
  C = std::strtod(argv[3], &eptr);

  tmax = 2000;
  cour = C*tau/h;
  cour2 = cour* cour;
  size = 18*13*1024;

  double *nxt_layer=nullptr;
  double *layer_1=nullptr;
  double *layer_2=nullptr;
  double *rev_layer=nullptr;

  dim3 blockSize = dim3(1024);
  dim3 gridSize = dim3(size/blockSize.x);

  float time;
  cudaTimer timer;

  cudaError_t ret = cudaMallocManaged(&nxt_layer, sizeof(double) * size);

  if (ret != cudaSuccess)
  {
    std::cout << cudaGetErrorString(ret) << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  ret = cudaMallocManaged(&layer_1, sizeof(double) * size);

 if (ret != cudaSuccess)
 {
    std::cout << cudaGetErrorString(ret) << std::endl;
    return 1;
 }

 ret = cudaMallocManaged(&layer_2, sizeof(double) * size);

 if (ret != cudaSuccess)
 {
    std::cout << cudaGetErrorString(ret) << std::endl;
    return 1;
 }

  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
  {
    layer_1[i] = exp(-(i*h-7)*(i*h-7)/2)*((i*h-7)*(i*h-7)-1);
  }
  for (int i = 1; i < size/2; ++i)
  {
    nxt_layer[i] = layer_1[i+1]+0.5*cour2*(layer_1[i+1]-2*layer_1[i]+layer_1[i-1]);
  }

  nxt_layer[0] = 0; nxt_layer[size-1] = 0;

  for (int i = size/2; i < size-1; ++i)
  {
    nxt_layer[i] = layer_1[i+1]+0.25*0.5*cour2*(layer_1[i+1]-2*layer_1[i]+layer_1[i-1]);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < size-1; ++i)
  {
    layer_2[i] = layer_1[i];
    layer_1[i] = nxt_layer[i];
  }

  nxt_layer[0] = 0; nxt_layer[size-1] = 0;

  timer.start();
  for (double t = 0; t < tmax; t=t+tau)
  {
         step<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(nxt_layer, layer_1, layer_2, cour2, size);
         if (CHECK_ERROR(cudaDeviceSynchronize()))
                throw(-1);
         nxt_layer[size-1]=0;
         nxt_layer[0]=0;
  }
  time = timer.stop();

  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
  {
          cout<<i*h<<" "<<nxt_layer[i]<<endl;
  }

}
```

step.cu

```
inline __device__ double compute(double *layer_1_tmp, double layer_2_tmp, double cour2)
{
        return __fmaf_rd(cour2, layer_1_tmp[0]+layer_1_tmp[2], __fmaf_rd(2.0-2*cour2,layer_1_tmp[1],-layer_2_tmp));
}

__global__ void step(double *tmp_layer, double *layer_1, double *layer_2, double cour2, int Nx)
{
        int node = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

        if(node >= Nx-1 || node<=0) return;

        double layer_1_tmp[3];

        layer_1_tmp[0]=layer_1[node-1];
        layer_1_tmp[1]=layer_1[node];
        layer_1_tmp[2]=layer_1[node+1];

        double layer_2_tmp=layer_2[node];

        if(node<=Nx/2)
        {
              tmp_layer[node] = compute(layer_1_tmp, layer_2_tmp, 0.25*cour2);
        }
        else
        {
               tmp_layer[node] = compute(layer_1_tmp, layer_2_tmp, cour2);
        }

        layer_2[node]=layer_1[node];
        layer_1[node]=tmp_layer[node];
}
```

I calculate GFlops as

```
long long int perfomance = size*tmax/tau;
long long int perftime = 1000*perfomance/time;
double gflops =(8*perfomance/time)/1000000;
```

I would be grateful for any of your comments and tips.

Comment: It will be extremely difficult to approach peak flops with 1D finite differences -- the arithmetic intensity compared to memory bandwidth requirements are not very favorable. But you will do better if you coalesce loads to shared memory and do the stencil calculation on a cached shared memory line instead of what you are doing. There is some very old (maybe 2007-2008 era) publications from NVIDIA on optimization of high order finite differences for seismic applications. You would be well served to do some reading of those

Answer (score -1):

In the kernel, each work-item is doing only several multiplications and additions. This is negligible compared to kernel launch overhead per cuda thread and the memory access latency per layer_1 element. It's equivalent of measuring a few nanoseconds within microseconds of kernel time. Try clock measurement around the compute() function calls. It would at least give some "cycles per compute" measurement and you can find the total performance during the compute call.

```
clock_t c1 = clock();
compute();
clock_t c2 = clock();
timings[node] = c2-c1;
```

Even this is not true performance measurement as it doesn't take pipelining into consideration when multiple compute calls are made one after another. You may add another compute call after first one and gain even more performance due to pipelining and latency hiding.

Answer (score -2):

Many (more consumer-oriented or semi-professional) graphics cards have better single precision than double precision performance. The single precision performance of the GTX 970 is 32x as high as its double precision performance.

Change the used data types from double to float.

Comment: GeForce GTX 970

Comment: After replacing double with float, Gflops =40. This is certainly good, but as far as I understand the limit is 3920/13 = 300 GFLops. What is slowing down the program so much ?

Comment: Can you please post the results running Compute Nsight? Memory accesses probably are the next reason. Change layer_1_tmp to variables (perhaps the optimizer catches that). Reading node-1, node and node+1 can be reduced to one global read and further be done with shared memory and/or warp shuffle instructions under special consideration of the first and last node.

Comment: This is really a comment and not an answer

Comment: The answer improved the performance by 3.5x. I reformulated a bit.

Comment: @Sebastian I can't post the results running Compute Nsight, because I connect via ssh to the computer where is the video card

Comment: There is a cli (command-line-interface) version available, too